# Connect Advantage Database through JNDI in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, advantage-database-server

I am facing few issues while connecting to Advantage Databse through JNDI using spring.

I tried to connect Advantage Database with the below code is working.

```
<bean id="peopleSoftDataSource" destroy-method="close" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    < property name="driverClassName" value="com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver"/>
    < property name="url" value="jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262/test/test.add;User=testuser;Password=testuser"/>
< /bean>
```

Where as if am connecting through JNDI, am getting the exception as login failed. I dont know why it is not working through JNDI

```
applicationcontext.xml configuration

< bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"><br/>
    < property name="jndiName" value="peopleSoftDataSource" /><br/>
    < property name="resourceRef" value="true" /><br/>
< /bean>

server.xml configuration

< Resource driverClassName="com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver" maxActive="4" maxIdle="2" maxWait="5000" name="jdbc/PeopleSoft"
removeAbandoned="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262/test/test.add;User=testuser;Password=testuser;" />
```

Kindly someone help with the above issue.

Comment: When it is not working, what is the error code in the exception? And what is the exception class?

Comment: Hi Alex,
Below is the error am getting..

Caused by: com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSException: [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage JDBC]Login failed.

Comment: That error message is only thrown when the server refused connection from the client. The exception should have an associated error code, ex.getErrorCode, that can narrow down the problem further. You can check the ads_err.adt on the server for the error code.

Comment: Hi Alex,
Am new to the ADS, Kindly let me know where to check ads_err.adt file for log errors.

I am connecting to ADS Server Remotely.

Thanks,
Rishi

Comment: 1. The ADSException object is a subclass of SQLException so you should be able to call myException.getErrorCode to display the error code.

Comment: 2. You can find the location of the ads_err.adt on the server using the ads_cfg.exe utility. It is installed with the ADS server. You will need to use an application such as arc32.exe [http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=19&Product=8&Platform=6] to view the file.

Comment: Hi Alex,
I tried to get the errorcode; which i got as 7056.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi Alex,
i found the resolution Now it is working fine.

Thanks alot for your help.

Thanks,
Rishi

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with using JNDI, however, I notice that there is a discrepancy in the name of the data source between the two xml configuration files. One has "peopleSoftDataSource" and the other has just "peopleSoft". Could that be the problem?

Comment: Hi Alex,
We will be mapping the name with context.xml,

<Context path="/wear-mopar" reloadable="true" swallowOutput="true">
  <ResourceLink global="jdbc/PeopleSoft" name="dataSource" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>

This seems ok here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it is working fine now.

we have to provide the path as below

< Resource driverClassName="com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver" maxActive="4" maxIdle="2" maxWait="5000" name="jdbc/PeopleSoft"
    removeAbandoned="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262;catalog=C:/ProfitMaker/ASIPlays/asipm.add;user=asiadsuser;password=asiadsuser"/>

instead of below

< Resource driverClassName="com.extendedsystems.jdbc.advantage.ADSDriver" maxActive="4" maxIdle="2" maxWait="5000" name="jdbc/PeopleSoft"
removeAbandoned="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262/test/test.add;User=testuser;Password=testuser;" />

Thanks,
Rishi